# How to get all database tables referenced in a presto query using presto-parser

Tags: java, presto

I'm using [presto-parser](https://github.com/prestodb/presto/tree/master/presto-parser) to figure out which database tables are being queried in any given Presto query. I implemented a class that extends [DefaultTraversalVisitor](https://github.com/prestodb/presto/blob/master/presto-parser/src/main/java/com/facebook/presto/sql/tree/DefaultTraversalVisitor.java) like this

```
public class ProcessTables extends DefaultTraversalVisitor<Void, Void> {
  private Set<String> tables;

  ProcessTables() {
    this.tables = new LinkedHashSet<>();
  }

  Set<String> getTables() {
    return tables;
  }

  @Override
  protected Void visitTable(Table node, Void context) {
    this.tables.add(node.getName().toString());
    return visitQueryBody(node, context);
  }
}
```

However, I find that conceptual tables (I'm not sure of the correct term here) are also treated as Tables without a way to distinguish them from actual database tables. For example

```
with RANDOMNAME as (
    select  column_a, column_b
    from    db.tablename
    where   condition
)
```

would `visitTable` for both `RANDOMNAME` and `db.tablename`. Is there a better way to do this? Am I missing something, like another method that I should override as well to distinguish between the two?

Comment: We have implemented `EXPLAIN TYPE IO` for this purpose. See `EXPLAIN (TYPE IO, FORMAT JSON)` example in docs https://prestosql.io/docs/current/sql/explain.html

Comment: BTW as you're doing Presto-based development, I invite you to join [Presto community slack](https://prestosql.io/slack.html) where you can meet fantastic Presto Community, as well as the creators of Presto. And get additional help with things like this one.

Comment: thank you for the pointer @PiotrFindeisen to `EXPLAIN`. Does this mean that I would have to submit the query to the engine and not statically analyse the query via the `presto-parser`?

Comment: Yes, this is what I would do. Parsing the query is not sufficient to identify the tables, this is what analysis is about. Replicating this logic outside of Presto can be hard. If your solution needs to work e.g. in "90% of cases", parser-based approach may be sufficient. For full solution I would definitely go with EXPLAIN.